# "Allow gmail to manage email links" doesn't exist

Tags: google-chrome

When I use google chrome on any other computer, I get this:

[image]

However on this computer I don't:

[image]

I am using chrome version `30.0.1599.101 m`. How do I get that? I am synced on the other computers so all my settings/themes/extensions/etc are the same.

Comment: chrome://settings/content is where the settings are. Under the "Handlers" subject in the settings.

Comment: @Darius That worked, thanks. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome://settings/content is where the settings are. Under the "Handlers" subject in the settings